# JSON Cookies cannot be parsed

Tags: node.js, json, sqlite, cookies

I'm using SQLite3 in node.js to extract cookies from the chrome browser and write the parsed JSON cookies to a .json file on the desktop.

My issue is that when I try to load them into a browser extension (which allows you to log into previous sessions using the cookies), but I get errors saying that certain values couldn't be parsed.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6Gww.jpg) is one example out of the like 10 errors.

I was expecting it to be able to log me into my accounts on another browser.

Does anyone know why this is happening in my code? Thanks.

```
    const query = `SELECT host_key, name, value, path, expires_utc, is_secure, is_httponly FROM cookies`;
    db.all(query, [], (err, rows) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(`Error querying ${browser.name} cookie database:`, err.message);
        return;
      }

      // Export the cookies to a file
      const fileName = `${browser.name}_cookies.json`;
      const filePath = path.join(os.homedir(), 'Desktop', fileName);
      const cookies = rows.map((row) => {
        return {
          domain: row.host_key,
          name: row.name,
          value: row.value,
          path: row.path,
          expires: row.expires_utc + (11644473600 * 1000),
          secure: row.is_secure,
          httpOnly: row.is_httponly
        };
      });
      fs.writeFileSync(filePath, JSON.stringify(cookies, null, 2));
      console.log(`Exported ${cookies.length} cookies from ${browser.name} to ${filePath}`);

      // Close the browser cookie database
      db.close();
    });
```